Clarification about argument why $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin(\text{ln}(n))}{n}$ diverge
I would like to clarify some aspects in this answer by Noam D. Elkies proving divergence of
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin(\text{ln}(n))}{n}.$$
Firstly, do I understand the general strategy correctly that divergence is obtained since the answer shows that the sequence violates Cauchy convergence test? Is this the "upshot"?
Secondly, why for
$$
N_1 = \Bigl\lceil \exp\Bigl((k+\frac16)\pi\Bigr) \Bigr\rceil, \quad
N_2 = \Bigl\lfloor \exp\Bigl((k+\frac56)\pi\Bigr) \Bigr\rfloor.
$$
we have implication that as $N_1 / N_2 \rightarrow \exp(2\pi/3)$ for $k \rightarrow \infty$, then $\sum_{n=N_1}^{N_2} \frac1n \rightarrow 2\pi/3$?
I not understand the last implication why convergence of the fraction implies convergence against $ 2\pi/3$ of this sum. Could somebody elaborate why this implication holds? Taking log of $N_1 / N_2$ if I not missing something doesn't give this sum $\sum_{n=N_1}^{N_2} \frac1n $, so this step appears mysterious.

Use the well-known asymptotics $\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{k} = \log N+\gamma +o(1)$.

@Gary: I see, so taking differences for sums with $N = N_2$ and $N_1$ kills $\gamma$ (...btw: what is this constant $\gamma$?) and we obtain with properties of log the asymptotics $\sum_{k=N_1}^{N_2} \frac{1}{k} = \log N_1/N_2+o(1)$, so are almost there, but how to deal with $o(1)$? Doesn't is cause a constant shift preventing it to convererge precisely against $2 \pi/3$, but instead agains a term of form $2 \pi/3 + K$ with a priori unknown "error constant" $K$? Or am I missing something there and it suffice to get the wanted convergence?

Gamma is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Look it up. The definition of little o is that it tends to zero as the large variable tends to infinity.

@Gary: right, sorry mixed up the def for little with big o notion, then everything fits together, thanks!

It wouldn't make sense to add gamma if it was big O.
